# why Android Virtual Device didn't run my project?

Tags: java, android

Android didn't show my project. I am in a beginner stage. When I click on the build icon top of the corner the android virtual device starts but cannot run my project. It just shows the home screen. and i get this error again and again. I am using AMD processo. So i cannot install intel hardware acceleration app. The log,
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037

12:38 AM    adb: CreateFileW 'nul' failed: The system cannot find the file specified. (2)

12:38 AM    * failed to start daemon

12:38 AM    error: cannot connect to daemon

12:38 AM    'C:\Users\Akira\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary

The first image is my build project. [run screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdgkA.jpg)

The emulator screen [Android emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09K89.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO community

There might be a couple of reasons of your problem, so start off by below

In terminal bottom tab,

[image]

Go to the location of your sdk tools under ..\sdk\platform-tools, and then run below commands

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

and let me if you need further support.

Comment: I cannot run ADB. Always get those errors.

Unable to create Debug Bridge: Unable to start adb server: * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
adb: CreateFileW 'nul' failed: The system cannot find the file specified. (2)
* failed to start daemon
error: cannot connect to daemon
'C:\Users\Akira\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary

Comment: You may open your windows task manager, go to processes tab, iselect adb.exe if found , RClick & end process; close android studio & start it again, then repeat above commands again; if all that not working. then replace your SDK tools with older version, you can get one from https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools.html#tos-header ... hope this works with you